# Better to modify Tab Bar or to create my own custom Tab Bar?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitabbarcontroller

I have a fairly complicated Tab Bar design that I want to implement which involves custom buttons/views.

I came across this article that explains how to implement my own custom Tab Bar:

https://guides.codepath.com/ios/Creating-a-Custom-Tab-Bar

But, as you can see, the article starts off immediately by saying that:

> This tutorial doesn't use views or memory as effective as standard iOS tab bar, mainly not applicable for production on its current state. Use it with cautious, customizing original tab bar isn't that hard, so use it wisely.

So my question is, how true is this? Would it just be better to painstakingly modify Apple's own Tab Bar to match my design needs rather than to create my own custom Tab Bar using the tutorial above?

Comment: "Better" in what way? Remember, you have not told us _what_ your design is. And you have tipped the scales by calling one way "tedious". Can you refocus this question so that it is about programming rather than just a matter of opinion or guesswork?

Comment: @matt Better in terms of memory usage. The article makes it clear that implementing a custom tab bar is worse for memory usage. How true is this?